Functor $G: \mathbf{Sets}\rightarrow {}_k\mathbf{Mod}$ proof
I've been given this exercise:

If $X$ is a set and $k$ is a field, define the vector space $k^X$ to be the set of all functions $X\rightarrow k$ under pointwise operations. Prove that there is a functor $G:\mathbf{Sets}\rightarrow {}_k\mathbf{Mod}$ with $G(X)=k^X$.

My question is: how can I define $G(f)$? I've tried defining it and run with it, but the arrows are pointing the wrong way.

This is my attempt:

If $X\in \text{obj}(\mathbf{Sets})$ then $G(X)\in\text{obj}({}_k\mathbf{Mod})$

We will show that $G(X)$ is a vector space. Let $\mathbf u,\mathbf v, \mathbf w:X\rightarrow k$ be set functions, then define

$(\mathbf {u+v})(x)=\mathbf u(x)+\mathbf v(x)$
$(\mathbf{au})(x)=a\mathbf u(x)$

Let also $\mathbf 0(x)=0$. The rest of the axioms follows, since $k$ is a field.

$(\mathbf u+\mathbf v)+\mathbf w=\mathbf u+(\mathbf v+\mathbf w)$
$\mathbf u+\mathbf v=\mathbf v+\mathbf u$
$\mathbf 0+\mathbf v=\mathbf v$
For every $\mathbf v$, there exists $-\mathbf v\in k^X$ such that $\mathbf v+(-\mathbf v)=\mathbf 0$
$(ab)\mathbf u=a(b\mathbf u)$
$a(\mathbf u+\mathbf v)=a\mathbf u+a\mathbf v$
$(a+b)\mathbf v=a\mathbf v+b\mathbf v$


If $f:X\rightarrow X'$ then $G(f):G(X)\rightarrow G(X')$

I can't think of a way to make a map such as $G(f)$. I have found
$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
X @>{s}>>k
\\
@V{f}VV @V{\text{id}}VV
\\
X' @>{s'}>>k
\end{CD}
so that $$s=s'\circ f$$ but this gives $G(f):G(X)\leftarrow G(X')$. Can this be fixed?

If $X\overset{f}{\rightarrow}X'\overset{g}{\rightarrow}X''$ then $G(X)\overset{G(f)}{\rightarrow}G(X')\overset{G(g)}{\rightarrow}G(X'')$ with $$G(g\circ f)=G(g)\circ G(f)$$

Again, this doesn't seem to work with the $G(f)$ I constructed. I get
$$G(X)\overset{G(f)}{\leftarrow}G(X')\overset{G(g)}{\leftarrow}G(X'')$$ Let $s'':X''\rightarrow k$, then

$G(g\circ f)(s'')=s''\circ (g\circ f)$
$(G(f)\circ G(g))(s'')=G(f)\circ (s''\circ g)=(s''\circ g)\circ f$

These two are equal in $\mathbf{Sets}$, but I get $G(g\circ f)=G(f)\circ G(f)$.

$G(1_X)=1_{G(x)}$ for all $X\in\text{obj}(\mathbf{Sets})$

Let $f:X\rightarrow X'$. Then $G(f\circ 1_X)=G(f)=G(1_X)\circ G(f)$ for all $f\in\text{Hom}_k(X,X')$. Since the identity on $G(X)$ is unique, we have $G(1_X)=1_{G(X)}$.
